# How to set select element font name on click in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

If text in div is clicked, font name of select element shoudl displayed in select, for example `Comic Sans MS`

I tried html

```
<select id="fs">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
</select>


<br/>

<div id="changeMe" style='font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'>

  click here</div>
```

with javascript

```
$(function() {
  $("#changeMe").on('click', function() {
    $('#fs').val($(this).css("font-family"));
  });

});
```

After clicking in `click here` select element is empty.

How to fix it so that font name `Comic Sans MS` appears in select?
I tried to use toString() in Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/0Lce9ob9/8/

but select box is still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the shown `option` based on the CSS of the `div` (rather than the other way around, as I understood previously) you could use the following:

```
$("#changeMe").on('click', function() {
  var font = $(this).css("font-family");
  $('#fs option[value=' + font + ']').prop("selected", true);
});
```

Simply changing the `value` of the `select` element itself won't accomplish what you want: you need to explicitly modify the `option` that you want shown. To get all the `option` elements with a `value` of `Comic Sans MS`, you would use:

```
$("option[value='Comic Sans MS']")
```

Also, note when you write an `id` attribute in HTML, you do *not* include the hash `#` mark. That's only when selecting the element in CSS. Finally, whenever you're using a `font-family` whose name contains spaces, you must wrap it in quotes. So your `<div>` should be like this:

```
<div id="changeMe" style='font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'>click here</div>
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
$("#changeMe").on('click', function() {
  var font = $(this).css("font-family");
  $('#fs option[value=' + font + ']').prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fs">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
</select>


<br/>

<div id="changeMe" style='font-family:"Comic Sans MS"'>

  click here</div>
```

Comment: select element must show div font size. Answer does the opposite: it sets font name form select. How to fix this so that after clicking in div content font name appears in select ? There is no input element. Updated question contains corrected fiddle.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. You didn't mention anything about the font size in your question. Could you edit it to explain what you mean?

Comment: Ah, I see: so when you click the `input`, the `option` whose value matches whatever was written in the `input` becomes selected. I'll edit my answer accordingly. My question remains about the font size.

Comment: I updated question and fiddle with your suggestions but problem persists in chrome if multi word font names are used. how fo fix this ? New fiddle is  http://jsfiddle.net/0Lce9ob9/6/

Comment: Should there be a space between `option` and `[value='Comic Sans MS']` at `$("option [value='Comic Sans MS']")` ?

Comment: @guest271314 No. `option [value='Comic Sans']` would mean "Select every element with a `value` of `Comic Sans` that's inside an `option`." Without the space it means, "Select every `option` with a `value` of `Comic Sans`."

Comment: @RobertAKARobin `$("option [value='Comic Sans MS']")` would not return any elements given `html` at Question http://jsfiddle.net/0Lce9ob9/11/

Comment: @guest271314 That's because it needs to be wrapped in a `$(document).ready` first.

Comment: It is wrapped in `.ready()` at jsfiddle; `$(function() {})` is alias for `.ready()` . There do not appear to be any descendant elements of `option` having attribute `[value='Comic Sans MS']` at `html` at Question; space character within selector indicates second selector are child elements of first selector

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. `$("option [value='Comic Sans MS']")` is incorrect. `$("option[value='Comic Sans MS']")` is correct, and is what I wrote in my answer above.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin See this portion of Answer: _"To get all the option elements with a value of Comic Sans MS, you would use:

`$("option [value='Comic Sans MS']")`"_

Comment: Ahh. I was looking at my code snippet, not what I wrote above it. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` to remove single quote `'` characters from `#changeMe` `font-family` value at `style` attribute, calling `.change()` event on `#fs` element

```
$(function() {
  $("#changeMe").on('click', function() {
    $('#fs').val(this.style.fontFamily.replace(/'/g, ""))
    .change();
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0Lce9ob9/9/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#` from your `div` id `changeMe`.

```js
$("#changeMe").on('click', function() {
    $('#fs option[value=' + $(this).css('font-family') + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fs">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div id="changeMe" style='font-family:Comic Sans MS'>click here</div>
```

Comment: After running code snippet and clicking in click me select element is still empty. How to fix this so that Comic Sans MS appears in select box ?

Comment: @Azim How to fix this so that it works in Chrome also. If font name contains single word, it works in Chrome also. How to fix this so that multi word font names can used in Chrome ?

Comment: I tried code snippet in answer and in http://jsfiddle.net/0Lce9ob9/8/ using toString() but select box is still empty. How to fix this ?